How to assign content type automatically when serving a file in Django
I have a system where certain permissions are needed to view files, and I'm using django-guardian for the permissions. I want the file to be displayed in a new tab if the browser supports it, otherwise just download the file.
I can check the filename and manually set content type depending on the file extension, but there are too many and it seems like a stupid thing to do.
Here is the view:
@login_required
def ViewDocument(request, document_id):
    document = Document.objects.get(id=document_id)
    path = document.file.name
    # Check user permissions to view file
    if not request.user.has_perm('home.view_document', document):
        return HttpResponseForbidden("You don't have permission to access this media.")

    # Construct the full path to the media file
    media_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

    # can i do this more easily?
    if path.endswith('.pdf'):
        temp_content_type = "application/pdf"
    elif path.endswith('.png'):
        temp_content_type = "image/png"
    elif path.endswith('.jpg'):
        temp_content_type = "image/jpeg"
    else:
        temp_content_type = "application/octet-stream"

    # Serve the file
    with open(media_path, 'rb') as file:
        response = HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type=temp_content_type)

    return response


Have a look at python-magic to identify the mime types automatically.

@dgw it is better to allow python handle this. Python has an mimetypes module. Besides, Django’s FileResponse can also handle this.

Use Django’s FileResponse objects to serve a file. All the nitty-gritty will be handled for you under the hood.
return FileResponse(open(media_path, 'rb'))[1]

The Content-Length header is automatically set when it can be guessed from the content of open_file.
The Content-Type header is automatically set when it can be guessed from the filename, or the name of open_file.

No need for multiple if statements just to determine these.

[1] The file will be closed automatically, so don’t open it with a context manager. Give FileResponse an open file.
